# How to check if NSString contains a string with a specific format?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, foundation

How can I detect if a certain NSString contains a string format like this for example:

I would like to check if a string is in a certain format. For example if I have the string format, `@"%d %d/%d %@"`, I would like my code to return YES if I compare it against `@"1 1/2 oz"`, and like wise would return NO if I compared it against `@"20 ml"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use are regular expressions. The regex for this specific case is

```
[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\/[0-9]+\ [a-zA-Z]+
```

Try using [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here's also a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html/).

Comment: I tried putting that into a string @"[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\/[0-9]+\ [a-zA-Z]+", but Xcode is giving me a warning saying "unknown escape sequence \/".

Comment: Then remove the \ before the / :)

Comment: But I still want to detect that slash character. I just tried it though and even though I am getting a compiler warning it still seems to be working. Thank You.

Comment: [Backslash will escape both $ and \\](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:yourPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive  error:&error];
```